# 1. how to prevent dmesg loose previous messages, how to restore it, 2. what has become of "kmesg"?

Tags: linux, dmesg

I have just got a serious problem: after about 7 days of use, my usb stick with eternal bash history seems not to work more.

Thus I began to search in dmesg. I invoked dmesg by

```
dmesg -s $((10*1024*1024)) -T | less
```

dmesg had shown all messages from beginning at boot time up to the moment. This was ok.

In order to prove if I correctly interpret the dmesg message "PM: suspend", I have switched the computer in the sleep state. After 5 minutes I awaked the computer (a TUXEDO Notebook, kubuntu 22.04 in live test mode from a bought usb stick).

Now dmesg shows only the messages from 26.10.2023 up to the moment, in less about 2000 lines.

```
ls -la /var/log/dmesg*
```

shows only one file.

Please, how can I get back all the dmesg message since boot time.

I remembered that many years ago I used a permanent running script which used kmesg and saved in some intervals the messages to a file.

In my system is no kmesg, and even in internet  google does'n find kmesk. What has happend?

Regards